# Move some of the methods into a different file?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a lot of OnClick and similar events in my main form. It's hard to navigate between them where they all are in Unit1.pas. 
I moved them to a different pas file and added this in my Unit1.pas:

```
{$INCLUDE Menu.pas}
```

But now the Delphi wants to remove OnClick events. So it doesn't work properly.
How do I split my code into different files?

Comment: Don't do this. Keep them in the same file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But there's 10,000 lines of just events.

Comment: @Tom: Then it seems likely that you can refactor the code by moving code out from these event handlers. For instance, if you have a `TButton.OnClick` handler that darkens a bitmap image on the form, you can extract the bitmap-darkening code into a procedure `DarkenBitmap(Bitmap: TBitmap)` and put that in a unit named `BitmapUtils`. Then your event handler can simply call this method, reducing its line count from 35 (say) to 3 (say).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand It's a good tip but I already did it: `procedure TForm1.Alpha1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Filter(F_ExtractAlpha, 5);
end;`

Comment: Your problem isn't going to be solved by putting the events in another file. Your code is just as big a mess, but now it sprawls. If you've got a single class with 10kloc implementing events, you have far bigger problems. You should refactor the code to address that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have a huge menu, lots of buttons. It's a big program.

Comment: Whatever. I'm pretty confident that include files with 10kloc are not going to make things better.

Comment: As many have said in the comments to your question - refactor. It might also be helpful to make some frames if your form lends itself to that approach. Also, if you have many controls that do almost exactly the same thing (lets say you have 10 buttons that call some method but with parameters 1 through 10) you might try to assign the same action to all controls, set the tag of each control to 1-10 and check the senders tag in the event.

Comment: If navigating thru your code is your main concern, you could load MMX CodeExplorer (An IDE addon, see https://www.mmx-delphi.de/) which has feature that helps navigate quickly in the source code. Actually, I can't leave without it.

Comment: If you have a large number of similar buttons, you can create them programmatically and assign them the same event handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't move a Form's event handlers to an `.inc` file, the IDE won't know how to handle that.  Event handlers assigned *at design-time* need to be locatable and editable, and that means they must be in the same source file as the Form itself.

What you can do instead is move the event handlers to a `TDataModule` that is created before, and is used by, the Form in question.  As long as the DataModule's unit is included in the Form's `uses` clause in the Form's `interface` section, the IDE should allow you to assign the event handlers *at design-time*.  If you use the Object Inspector to create new event handlers, you will have to move them to the DataModule manually and re-assign the events accordingly.

Otherwise, all you can really do is refactor your code to reduce the amount of code in each event handler, or even reduce the number of event handlers used.  And then you can use the Code Editor's code folding feature to hide the remaining code so you don't see it but it still exists to the IDE and compiler.